# Convert basic auth from java to dart

Tags: java, flutter, dart, base64

I have java code of basic auth and I want to convert do dart. Here is java code

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("user_id", (Number) userId);
jsonObject.addProperty("access_token", userToken);
try {
  String encodeToString = Base64.encodeToString(jsonObject.toString().getBytes(Key.STRING_CHARSET_NAME), 2);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("Basic ");
  sb.append(encodeToString);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I did in flutter but I am not getting the same results. Here is how I did in the `flutter`.

```
String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('${box1.get('user_id')}:${box1.get('user_token')}'));
```

I think I am doing something wrong with `JsonObject` in java. Or maybe this part is confusing me.

`Base64.encodeToString(jsonObject.toString().getBytes(Key.STRING_CHARSET_NAME), 2);`

In my code both `${box1.get('user_id')} and ${box1.get('user_token')}` are string I mean I am not getting as a json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  String credentials = userId + ":" + access_token;
  Codec<String, String> strToBase64 = utf8.fuse(base64);
  String authEncoded = strToBase64.encode(credentials);
  String basicAuth = = 'Basic ' + authEncoded;
```